# Laravel 5.5 - Handle Error Exception for 'where'

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.5 I am trying to handle an error exception like this...

```
        try {
            $fruits = Fruit::where('fruit_id', $user->fruit->id)->get();
        }

        catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {

            return Response::json(array(
                'error' => true,
                'status_code' => 400,
                'response' => 'fruit_id not found',
            ));

        }
```

But this is giving me a 'Trying to get propert of non-object' error

The same error handling works correctly for findorfail, how should I be doing this for the 'where' statement?

Comment: check $user->fruit->id contains proper value. Just try to print.

Comment: It doesn't return any results, I am expecting that.  My question though is how to catch that error and return a JSON response

Comment: if you are using catch (\Exception $e), what will be the result ?

Comment: `$user->fruit->id` is throwing a different exception than a `ModelNotFoundException`. I can't remember which by heart, but it's easy to check - just change it to `\Exception $e` like @Sunil says, then check which kind it is through `get_class($e)` and change the line accordingly. :)

Comment: The error show "exception": "ErrorException"

Comment: try to return the user->fruit first see what it returns. 'Trying to get propert of non-object' error occurred because you are accessing the user->fruit->id which might not exist for some user.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are passing wrong values in your where query in the try block.

```
try {
      $fruits = Fruit::where('fruit_id', $user->fruit->id)->get();
    }
```

Is it fruit_id or just id because you are querying it on fruit model itself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some pointers in the comments I changed to

```
  try {
        $fruits = Fruit::where('fruit_id', $user->fruit->id)->get();
    }

    catch(\Exception $e) {

        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'status_code' => 400,
            'response' => 'fruit_id not found',
        ));

    }
```

All is now working now I am catching the correct exception

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Laravel 5.7

```
try {
    $fruits = Fruit::where('fruit_id', $user->fruit->id)->get();
}

catch(\Exception $e) {

    abort(404);

}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you got it working, I'd like to make mention of Laravel's [Exception Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#the-exception-handler).

The [report method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#report-method) allows you to catch any exception type and customize how you wish to process and move forward. There is a report helper function as well which is globally accessible.

Furthermore, [reportable and renderable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#renderable-exceptions) exceptions allow you to create and customize your responses.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code:

```
if ($user->fruit) {
    try {
        $fruits = Fruit::where('fruit_id', $user->fruit->id)->get();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'status_code' => 400,
            'response' => 'fruit_id not found',
        ));
    }
} else {
    return "User Fruit doesn't exists!!";
}
```